# Limits for Web & Mobile app based on google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have read a lot, 1 but I still think I didn't find clear answers about the following questions:

1) A user of my web or mobile app uses an input in order to find Lat, Long of an address (I am using Javascript). Does this request represented by user's client IP or from my Server's IP?

I am asking because I want to ensure that this is a client side request in order to no overcome Google's [2,500 requests per IP](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat).

2) Then, once I have the lat,long in my database I can draw the google map based on an array of lat, long which my user had store previously. Is this a request from my server's IP or user's IP?

Comment: Are you writing a server side component to call google (and store the response in your db) or is it happening from the end user's browser?

Comment: I am using pure Javascript no php no other server side language. Is that enough for you? Thank you.

Comment: @Kabamaru Yes I am using v3

Comment: The geocoding requests should be coming from the user's IP, not your IP since the request is originating from the user's browser and not from your server. 

You do not go against the Google server API to plot points using JavaScript on the client. Presumably this is how you are drawing the trail and should not have any impact on your per-IP limit.

Comment: Is this for a public site or private? If this app is created for internal use, each user may have their own IP within the network but still only have one external (public) IP for all users in the network. That could cause you problems with Google's limit too...

Comment: It's for a public web/mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Since the geocoding requests are going directly from the user's machine to Google, you are using what Google calls "client-side geocoding" which falls under slightly different licensing agreements than the 2,500/IP API limits.

> Client-side geocoding through the browser is rate limited per map session, so the geocoding is distributed across all your users and scales with your userbase. Geocoding quotas and rate limits drive the strategies outlined in this article.
>
> When running client-side geocode requests at periodic intervals, such as on a mobile app, your requests may be subject to blocking if all of your users are making requests at the same time (e.g. the same second of every minute). To avoid this, consider one of the following:
>
> - Use a caching strategy.
> - Introduce random intervals to your requests (jitter). Ensure requests are random across your entire userbase.
> - If developing for Android, use an inexact repeating alarm.
> - If developing for Android, select an appropriate location strategy.
>
> In Google Maps API for Business, quotas are tied to client IDs, which provide much higher quotas. To learn more about Maps API for Business quotas and error handling, we recommend reviewing our article, Usage Limits for Google Maps API Web Services. If you're still running into quota limits using the Google Maps API for Business, file a support request here: http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal/.